# Patch \input in tabular if on a recent LaTeX

Tags: errors, input

I am trying to implement a workaround for the error I get when inputting a table as external file in a file using `\input`. The code snippet below works for this purpose:

```
\IfFileExists{filename}
\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1 
{ \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
 \AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
 { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
 \AddToHook{env/tabular*/begin}
 { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

I now want to only apply it on some computers, not others, so wanted to put it inside `\IfFileExists`. I don't know whether it is the best solution, but it certainly does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\IfFileExists{filename}
{ \ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1 
{ \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
 \AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
 { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
 \AddToHook{env/tabular*/begin}
 { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
 \ExplSyntaxOff}
{}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I would like to make it work if possible. Alternative solutions would also be welcome. E.g., would it work to use `\IfFileExists` to define some other variable, and use it as argument to a conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better test in this case would be to test for the LaTeX format you are using.  If you have at least 2020-10-01, then you apply the code, otherwise do nothing.  You can test for that with `\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2020-10-01}`.

Then, you need to write `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off` outside of the argument, otherwise it will not work (similar to [`\makeatletter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/134574)).

The code would be like this:

```latex
\RequirePackage{expl3} % required for compatibility with older releases
\makeatletter
\providecommand\IfFormatAtLeastTF{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2020-10-01}
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
      { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
    \AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
    \AddToHook{env/tabular*/begin}
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
  }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It turns out, however, that a system running texlive 2019 leads to an error: "Undefined control sequence. \ExplSyntaxOn." Same with \ExplSyntaxOff. Interstingly (?), in 2019 placing \ExplSyntaxOn/Off inside argument fixes the error, but introduces it in 2021.

Comment: @nicolae Oh, right, with TeX Live before 2019 you have to load `expl3` explicitly (I added it in my answer).  Writing `\ExplSyntaxOn` inside the argument there is wrong (so much that it doesn't work for TL 2021), and it only works for TL 2019 because the False branch is taken

Comment: Yes, of course the false branch was taken, that was the whole point. I should have seen that right away.